# Visual C# Multithreaded UserControl DLL

Tags: c#, dll, user-controls

I would like to create a multithreaded Usercontrol with C#.
Is this possible with VisualStudio or only in C++? The idea behind is to initiate several instances of the control, so that each instance has its own memory segments and works inependent from the other instances...

**Background:**
I would like to use the control within SAP. In SAP I am able to create multiple instances of SAP GUI. Each SAP GUI instance contains my own (ActiveX) control. The example is a stop watch. Currently i start the stop watch in the first instance and all other instances are in sync. This is fine so far - but now I would like to change the UserControl (which is obviously a STA DLL) to an MTA DLL so that each instance of the control has its own time... Do I have any chance to compile it as an MTA DLL or is this not solving the issue (without changing the architecure)? Or am I completly wrong?

**Assumption:** The stopwatch is GDI based... The actual error which I am seeing is from code inside GDI+ that ensures the same Graphics object cannot be used in multiple threads. But how can I use the graphics object in multiple threads?

Comment: why don't you explain to us a bit more about what it is you're trying to do?  Yes, C# can handle multithreading.

Comment: What you describe is exactly the point of a UserControl and exactly what it does, even in C#. So what's your actual question? Also, UserControl, like all UI controls are rendered on the UI thread (which is the main thread). While you can make certain actions within the control threaded, I don't think you can do (or even make sense) to make the UserControl multithreaded as a whole

Comment: You need to provide more information, from those lines my crystal ball says you might be trying 1, 2 or 500 different things, provide some code example or explain better what you're trying to achieve, if possible what kind of project you're working on or, any clue that helps us figure out what you're trying to do. And welcome to StackOverflow where you get downvote for simply not googling enough before asking.

Comment: Each time you create a new UserControl, it's instance variables will be independent of other instances of that class. Only if you declare a variable `static` will it be shared among all the instances. Is that the sort of thing you mean by "has its own memory segments"?

Answer (score 1):

Base on the info you provided, yes you can, but for memory segment, its per process not controls inside the process, for 32-bit applications, max is 2GB, can be extended to 3GB but not recommended.

if you want independent memory then you must create multiple executables where each exe has its own address space.

so what you can do is create a C# application that has usercontrol or form and add your logic, this will be compiled into a separate exe, then create another C# application to start a process(es) for the first C# application.